# gsub() seems to don't have effect

Tags: r

I'm trying to delete part of the name of some cells of a data frame with gsub() but the function doesn't "have effect". The code I used is the following:

```
data<-data.frame(a1=rnorm(10),b1=rnorm(10),c1=rnorm(10))
gsub("-","",data$c1)
```

At the end the "-" remains in the cells of the column, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: You are not saving the result from the `gsub` function, try assigning it to `data$c1` again to save the values.

Comment: It worked, thank you very much!!